# React Styled component conditional interface based on `as` value passed as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

So I have a button design that I'm try to build for a component library that looks identical if it is a link or a button.

I figured having one component makes sense and depending on what I pass in the `as` prop, would define what interface is used.

For example if another dev does `<Button as="a">I'm a Button</Button>` it would error and say `href` needs to be defined. alternatively if you had `<Button as="button" href="http:youSuckAtTypescript.com">` it would complain that you cant have href on a `as="a"` and you are missing `type`

I'm really struggling with the typescript errors get on the `as` prop of my `Button.tsx` component and where I use the button on `App.tsx`. I think it might have something to do with re-defining `as` which I pass to styled components to change the rendered html.

Here is an example of where I have gotten it to:

https://codesandbox.io/s/conditional-props-m3w4s

Any help in understanding where Im going wrong with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `HTMLAnchorElement | HTMLButtonElement` are the types for the elements themselves, not the names.  But typing this properly is giving me a headache.

Comment: You want something along these lines `type ButtonProps<T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements> = {
  color: "primary" | "secondary" | "black" | "white";
  sizing: "large" | "medium" | "small";
  buttonStyle: "fill" | "outline" | "text";
  as: T;
} & JSX.IntrinsicElements[T]`

`const Button = <T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements>(props: ButtonProps<T>) => {`